# jQuery: Get elments with custom attribute that has hidden child, add live hover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I wanted to get all elements that has a specific attribute and has a child of a specific type that is hidden. To do this, I wrote this selector:

```
$("*[custom-attr]:has('span:hidden')")
```

In addition to this, I wanted to add a live function on hover. For example like this:

```
$("*[custom-attr]:has('span:hidden')").live("hover", function() { /* do something */ });
```

I thought this was working properly, since I got the visual result I wanted. However, when using Firebug, I noticed that it was probably not perfect. When moving the mouse within the body, even if not hovering the elements that were meeting the selection, Firebug indicates that the HTML elements hovered are affected (they appear as yellow in Firebug HTML tab). See attached image:

[image: Firebug screenshot]

Why is this and how can I avoid it?

I noticed that a similar selector did not cause the same behavior, like this one to get elements without the span child:

```
$("*[custom-attr]:not(:has('span'))").live("hover", function() { /* do something */ });
```

Thanks.

Comment: try avoid  using `.live()` its deprecated..instead use `.on()`

Comment: You can install [Firediff](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firediff/) and check what actually changes in document.

Comment: @skobaljic Thanks, great add-on. Using this I noted that it added and instantly removed an id value ("sizcache") to the elements I hovered. I read a bit about sizcache, however I don't understand why it's used in the first example I described above and not in the second.

Comment: Probably because you used selector which is not supported by browser `:has()`, so jQuery use `sizcache` for calculations. I know it was used for sure on older IE when you use `nth-child` selector. So this may be the correct answer to your question. `subject of selector` will be implemented soon in css, but till than there is no way to naturally select parent element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using natural browser selectors and that way avoid jQuery adding temporary attributes. For your case, instead of `has()` you can use:

```
$("[custom-attr]").on("mouseenter", function() {
    if ( $(this).find('span:hidden').length ) {
        /* your code */
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're getting the visual results you are expecting, it sounds like it's working. I think Firebug simply highlights elements that have recently had something change on itself or, if collapsed in the HTML view like on your screenshot, somewhere among its children. This highlighting will happen both when e.g. an attribute is change and when the change is reverted on e.g. mouseleave, and the highlighting will stay for some time after the change has occurred.

That said, it's also a good idea, as Kartikeya mentioned in a comment, to switch from `.live()`, which is deprecated, to [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on).